# Remote Procedure Call Mechanisms between Android and Desktop Computers

Tags: java, android, rmi, rpc

I want to perform `Remote Procedure Calls` between Android and Desktop.

If RMI was there,it would have been mine choice.
But android does **not** support Java-RMI.

Can anybody suggest similar and simple RPC mechanisms that i can use as easily as RMI,without worrying about lower layer transport layer implementations

Kindly give me the alternative for RMI in android

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to use different strategies:
- Web Services calls using SOAP, XML RPC, using Rest invokations types.....many strategies
- alternatives to Web Services available like the one provided in Spring Remoting with Burlap/Hessian protocols (you are not obliged to be tied with Spring to use such strategies)
Main idea is to use as core component a protocol managed by your android device : HTTP...

HTH
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Versile Java](https://versile.com/products/vjava/) (full disclosure: I am one of the developers). It is in development but already quite stable, so you may want to have a look. Here is a [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWTwJ7L6onw) which shows an Android client using Versile Platform to interact with a python based service running on a desktop.

Answer (score -1):

RPC is generally a lousy technique, especially for remote operation.  And it's not supported in most UI environments because you're never supposed to "wait".  Far better to use some sort of a request/response approach.

Comment: 'Not supported in most UI environments' such as what? Java AWT and Swing are two prominent counterexamples. And not supported how? What measures are taken to prevent it?